# Unable to bind dynamic DataTable to Grid.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, grid

I want to use [Grid.MVC](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gridmvc) to create a grid (table). In this grid I want to bind to a DataTable, which is the Table I get from `SELECT * FROM TABLE`.

### View

My view looks like this:

```
@model DataTable
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewTable";
}
@using GridMvc.Html
@using System.Data
<h2>ViewTable</h2>
@Html.Grid(Model.Columns.Cast<IEnumerable<DataColumn>>()).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add().RenderValueAs(a => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Index"));
    foreach (DataColumn item in Model.Columns)
    {
        try
        {
            columns.Add(a => item).Titled(item.ColumnName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
})
```

> This always throws the error column `item` already exists in the grid
>   (at the second item).

I also tried it with a `for loop` instead of `foreach`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    var idx = i;
    try
    {
        columns.Add(a => Model.Columns[idx]).Titled(Model.Columns[idx].ColumnName);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Here I get the following exception (error message):

> Expression 'a => value(ASP._Page_Views_Home_ViewTable_cshtml).Model.Columns.get_Item(value(ASP._Page_Views_Home_ViewTable_cshtml+<>c__DisplayClass4).idx)' not supported by grid

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can put an if condition and skip adding that column.

```
try
{
    columns.Add(a => item).Titled(item.ColumnName);
    if (item.ColumnName == "Your Column name")
    {
        //skip that column
    }

}
```

Comment: no, that is not what I am looking for. For example the item-ColumnNames are `ID` and `NAME`, it still complains about ITEM. It has to do with the foreach loop I guess, but the for Loop also doesn't really work

Comment: @DavidWalser Did you ever find a solution for this problem?  I was getting the same exception that you saw in some code I'm working on.  Here is a link to the solution I found for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693538/gridmvc-looping-not-working-with-dynamic-column-name/53695991#53695991

Comment: @knot22 unfortunately I can't remember if I was able to solve this problem, and I have no access to this project anymore :/ I hope you will find a solution