# GridMVC looping not working with dynamic column name

Tags: c#

In a project, GridMVC is being used to generate reports.  The code below is used server side in methods that generate reports.  Unfortunately, the design of ReportRowDataContract.cs cannot be changed (ie. the sequentially numbered `ReportData` properties).

The code is written such that `ReportData` properties can have different data types on different reports (ie. on report A ReportData1 may have a data type of string while on report B ReportData1 might have a data type of integer...etc.).

In the `AddGridColumn` method of ReportGrid.cs there are 6 lines that use `Column.Add` (the first line has a comment that it's line #33 and the last line has a comment that it's line #38).  This works okay but I am trying to refactor this code using a loop to eliminate updates to ReportGrid.cs when a new `ReportData` property is added to ReportRowDataContract.cs.  See below for what I've tried and the problem encountered...

Here is the relevant code -

GridMVC:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using GridMvc.Columns;
using GridMvc.Html;
using GridMvc.Pagination;

namespace GridMvc
{
    public class Grid<T> : GridBase<T>, IGrid where T : class
    {
        public Grid(IEnumerable<T> items);
        public Grid(IQueryable<T> items);

        public IGridColumnCollection<T> Columns { get; }
        public bool DefaultFilteringEnabled { get; set; }
        public bool DefaultSortEnabled { get; set; }
        public virtual int DisplayingItemsCount { get; }
        public bool EnablePaging { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public IGridPager Pager { get; set; }
        public GridRenderOptions RenderOptions { get; set; }
        public ISanitizer Sanitizer { get; set; }
        public override IGridSettingsProvider Settings { get; set; }

        public virtual void AutoGenerateColumns();
        protected internal virtual IEnumerable<T> GetItemsToDisplay();
    }
}
```

ReportRowDataContract.cs:

```
namespace AcmeCorp.Services.Common.Global
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    public class ReportRowDataContract
    {
        public ReportDataDataContract ReportData1 { get; set; }            
        public ReportDataDataContract ReportData2 { get; set; }            
        public ReportDataDataContract ReportData3 { get; set; }            
        public ReportDataDataContract ReportData4 { get; set; }            
        public ReportDataDataContract ReportData5 { get; set; }            
        public ReportDataDataContract ReportData6 { get; set; }

        // an indexed property - for accessing report data properties by index (which is useful for looping)
        public ReportDataDataContract this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                return new ReportDataDataContract[]
                {
                  ReportData1,
                  ReportData2,
                  ReportData3,
                  ReportData4,
                  ReportData5,
                  ReportData6
                }[i];
            }
        }

        public int GetReportDataPropertyCount()
        {
            return typeof(ReportRowDataContract)
                .GetProperties()
                .Count(p => p.Name.StartsWith("ReportData"));
        }

    }
}
```

ReportDataDataContract.cs:

```
namespace AcmeCorp.Services.Common.Global
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    public class ReportDataDataContract
    {       
        public string Name { get; set; }        
        public string StringValue { get; set; }        
        public decimal? DecimalValue { get; set; }        
        public int? IntValue { get; set; }        
        public bool SumValue { get; set; }        
        public bool AvgValue { get; set; }        
        public int? Index { get; set; }
        public string DisplayFormat { get; set; }       
    }
}
```

ReportGrid.cs:

```
namespace AcmeCorp.WebApps.LMS.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using GridMvc;
    using AcmeCorp.Services.Common.Global;

    public class ReportGrid : Grid<ReportRowDataContract>
    {
        public ReportGrid(List<ReportRowDataContract> items) : base(items)
        {
            // get count of how many fields exist in ReportRowDataContract                     
            int reportDataPropertyCount = (new ReportRowDataContract()).GetReportDataPropertyCount();

            // create columns for grid from fields in ReportRowDataContract
            int i = 0;
            while (i + 1 < reportDataPropertyCount)
            {
                AddGridColumn(items[0][i], i);
                i++;
            }
        }

        private void AddGridColumn(ReportDataDataContract reportColumn, int i)
        {
            try
            {
                if (reportColumn != null)
                {
                    if (reportColumn.StringValue != null)
                    {
                             if (i == 0) Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.StringValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name); //line #33
                        else if (i == 1) Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData2.StringValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name);
                        else if (i == 2) Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData3.StringValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name);
                        else if (i == 3) Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData4.StringValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name);
                        else if (i == 4) Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData5.StringValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name);
                        else if (i == 5) Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData6.StringValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name); //line #38
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

My refactor attempt - replace lines 33 through 38 with this code:

```
Columns.Add(m => (new ReportDataDataContract()).StringValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name); //line #33
Columns.GetByName("StringValue").Name = "ReportData" + (i + 1).ToString() + ".StringValue"; //line #34
```

In debug mode, on the first pass through the loop where `reportColumn.StringValue != null`, when the cursor hovers over `Columns` on line 33, the Name shows as "StringValue".  After line 34 executes and the cursor hovers over `Columns` the Name shows as "ReportData1.StringValue".  However, an exception is thrown on the second pass through this loop.  Exception object details -

message: "Column 'StringValue' already exist in the grid"

source: "GridMVC"

stack trace:
   at GridMvc.Columns.GridColumnCollection`1.Add(IGridColumn`1 column)
   at GridMvc.Columns.GridColumnCollection`1.Add[TKey](Expression`1 constraint, Boolean hidden)
   at GridMvc.Columns.GridColumnCollection`1.Add[TKey](Expression`1 constraint)
   at AcmeCorp.WebApps.LMS.Models.ReportGrid.AddGridColumn(ReportDataDataContract reportColumn, Int32 i) in C:\Source\AcmeCorp\AcmeCorp.WebApps\AcmeCorp.WebApps.LMS\Models\ReportGrid.cs:line 33

It is behaving as though renaming the column does not get rid of the column's original name.  Why doesn't renaming the `Column` work?  What can be done to get it to add additional columns to the GridMVC via looping?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  Replacing lines 33 through 38 with this resolved the issue:

```
Columns.Add(m => (new ReportDataDataContract()).StringValue, "ReportData" + (i + 1).ToString() + ".StringValue").Titled(reportColumn.Name);
```

The "Grid.MVC with Dynamic Columns" post here https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gridmvc was the key to figuring this out.  In sample code there it was naming the column in the parenthesis that contain the lambda expression.